# How to add subquery in laravel query builder

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to convert my sql query to Laravel Query
From this

```
SELECT products.name,
(SELECT SUM(orders.date BETWEEN from_date AND to_date)
FROM orders WHERE orders.product_id = products.id ) as order_counts
FROM products;
```

Then I tried converting to laravel query builder but it results to an error:

```
Product::select('name', 
DB::raw("SUM(orders.date 
BETWEEN $request->from_date AND $request->to_date) AS total_orders
FROM orders WHERE orders.product_id = products.id"))
->get();
```

The error is syntax error on the $request->from_date inside db::raw.

Comment: what's kind of error?

Comment: results in an error... provides no error description...

Comment: I edited the question and add the error message

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `withCount` method: [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models)

```php
Product::select('name')->withCount([
    'orders' => function (Builder $query) using ($from_date, $to_date) {
        $query->whereBetween('date', [$from_date, $to_date]);
     }
]);
```

I saw you have edited your issue, and describe your error. When using variables in string you should put them in braces.

```php
Product::select('name', 
  DB::raw(
    "SUM(orders.date BETWEEN {$request->from_date} AND {$request->to_date}) AS total_orders FROM orders WHERE orders.product_id = products.id"
  )
)->get();
```

Comment: How about I had these subquery: ```(SELECT SUM(orders.order_date BETWEEN '2022-10-06' AND '2022-10-12') - SUM(orders.order_date BETWEEN '2022-10-06' - INTERVAL 14 DAY AND '2022-10-12' - INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
FROM products WHERE orders.product_id = products.id) as diff_order,```

Comment: You will have no other choice than using `DB::raw` method